«Хотел ли бы ты» vs «хотел бы ты»: which one (or maybe both) is correct and why?
I do not wish to harm anyone. If possible, I would like to ask such a question about Russian particles. It's English-speaking site so I respect the rules and ask in English.
Which interrogative Russian sentence is grammatically correct:
Хотел ли бы ты стать президентом?
or
Хотел бы ты стать президентом?
(or are they both right?)
Trust me, I am a native speaker and I am so ashamed I do not know the correct option yet.
I have tried to ask on another site; the answer was very kind-hearted but very dim/obscure.
Google didn't help too much either.

Грамота. ру. suggests several meanings of the particle ли in different  grammatical environments. Your example gives a general question. Both variants are equally used in speech and the difference is really small.
ЛИ
Большой толковый словарь русского языка
ЛИ; ЛЬ. I. частица (после того сл., к которому относится). 1. Усиливает вопросительный характер предложения.
Не нуждаетесь ли Вы в чём-нибудь? Вы здоровы ли? Взять ли нам с собой еду?
So ли is used after the word as an intencifier. It's up to you to decide whether to use it in the sentence or not.

If you don't use ли, then the fact that this is a question is only shown via the intonation. Of course, if you're a native speaker, the correct intonation of interrogative sentences will not be a problem for you. In fact, in English you can say both "do you want to go there?" (a clear question), and "you want to go there?" (with a question intonation, but otherwise not phrased as a question as such) too.
For non-native speakers, the intonation of Russian questions is less intuitive, but they use IC-3 (intonation contour 3), with a sharp rise in pitch on the word being emphasised in the question. There is often a choice of words to have this main rise in pitch in a question, depending on what you are trying to emphasise, but if you said хотел бы ты стать ПРЕЗИДЕНТОМ? with a strong rise in pitch on the final word, then it becomes clear that this is a question. You could also have a strong rise in pitch on the first word with a strong fall in pitch thereafter: ХОТЕЛ бы ты стать президентом?
English intonation is different - and varies between English dialects (eg. the intonation in Southern British English and in North America) - but at least in Southern England the pitch gradually moves up throughout the interrogative sentence, but without a strong rise in pitch on any word. It's a bit of specialised area, but it's clear if you study Russian that the intonation is very different.
